# USB flash drive formatted as "Linux Live CD" keeps the CD-ROM name after re-partitioning

Tags: linux, partition, usb, live-usb, iso

I have an USB flash drive that I formerly used as installation medium for Linux Fedora.

The stick still has the "Fedora Live USB" installation files on it. When I insert it into my olde laptoppe, it appears as disk named "Fedora-Live-KDE-x86_64-22-3" in KDE dolphin. Fair enough.

So, I destroy all partitions on it using `fdisk`, create new partition, set up an ext4 filesystem on said partition.

I insert the flash drive. I appears as "Fedora-Live-KDE-x86_64-22-3" in KDE dolphin.

*UNDEAD FLASH DRIVE TIME!*

Where does that name come from? Feels like it does not come from the USB flash drive, but factoid (3) below indicates that it actually does.

Where is that name coming from and how do I change it?

*Here is some research on where the name is coming from, the conclusion being that it apparently comes from the ISO-9660 data left on the disk. But how is this sane behaviour by Linux?*

▶ `e2label /dev/sdd1` shows nothing: the filesystem has no label

▶ `blkid /dev/sdd1` shows

`/dev/sdd1: UUID="10aab422-4212-45c8-9f99-35e5eb719154" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="5c4a815c-01"`

▶ Using the flash drive on another machine also results in the name "Fedora-Live-KDE-x86_64-22-3" being displayed.

▶ One can dump the "labels" (whatever those are) by looking at the filesystem under `/dev`:

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/`

This shows the symlink

`Fedora-Live-KDE-x86_64-22-3 -> ../../sdb`

Note that the symlink points to the device, not the partition. So this is not a filesystem label, but something like a "disk label".

▶ The original "filesystem label" obtainable with `e2label` being empty, we set it and then see what's up:

```
# e2label /dev/sdb1 "Scooby Doo"
# ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  9 Feb  4 23:43 Fedora-Live-KDE-x86_64-22-3 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Feb  4 23:43 Scooby\x20Doo -> ../../sdb1
```

So now both the disk and the filesystem/partition have a label. However, after removal/reinsertion, dolphin (or rather, Linux) now settles on the "Scooby Doo" name of the filesystem. And why not! We can then erase the label again using `e2label /dev/sdb1 ""` ... and then the name is back, but only partially: "Fedora-Live-KDE-" (why partially? because it's read from 0x9000 onwards, whereas the full label is at 0x8000, see below)

▶ Also tried to see what `parted` does. It seems mightily confused: It thinks the 8GiB stick with 512-byte blocks is actually a 32GiB stick with 2048-byte blocks and detects a Apple partition, while `fdisk` is absolutely happy with finding an 8GiB Linux partition. Curioser and curioser.

```
(parted) print
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048
bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel? i
Model: Generic USB Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 32.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   10.2kB  8192B                Apple
 2      88.1kB  5278kB  5190kB               EFI
 3      5319kB  26.1MB  20.8MB               EFI
```

It's probably not TOTALLY confused because on the stick we find this:

[image: Looks like a Mac thing]

▶ Additional weirdness: The reformatted USB stick seems to be un-writeable but traversable for a non-root user. Writing as root works though. But that's just a side remark.

▶ Getting a diskdump with `okteta` shows the disk name string at position just past 0x8000, i.e. in block 64 (blocks being 512-Byte-sized):

[image: okteta dump around 0x8000]

This evidently stems from the LiveCD structure.

▶ Looking further shows the name again likely in UTF-16 format just past 0x9000, with the version suffix dropped probably because the field has constant size:

[image: okteta dump around 0x9000]

▶ Time to POKE and see what happens. We modify the string at the 0x8000 mark:

[image: modifying string at around 0x8000]

We also modify the string at the 0x9000 mark:

[image: modifying string at around 0x9000]

Then write the blocks back to the stick (because we have been modifiying a file obtained using `dd`), sync, sync and eject.

Then reinsert the stick. Linux settles in this case on the string at 0x9000.

```
[root@elf ~]# ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Feb  9 22:09 DellUtility -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Feb  9 23:20 MOTHRA-Dead-KDE- -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Feb  9 22:09 OS -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Feb  9 22:09 RECOVERY -> ../../sda4
```

Dolphin shows the content of `/dev/disk/by-label`:

[image: the string has been modified]

So, we know where the string comes from. It does not seem useful to be able to change it as it comes from the CD-ROM structure, whereas we have put a standard partitioning scheme onto the USB disk. Why does Linux mash these two two structures?

Comment: Have you tried `dd if=zero of=/dev/sdb` (wiping it completely)?

Comment: @redfast00 That's next on the menu

Comment: Can you run `file -s /dev/sdb`

Comment: And `file -s /dev/sdb`

Comment: @redfast00 It says `/dev/sdb: ISO 9660 CD-ROM filesystem data 'Fedora-Live-KDE-x86_64-22-3' (bootable)`

Comment: Ha! Can you run `e2label /dev/sdb testname`?

Comment: @redfast00 Nah, taht doesn't work as there is no filesystem on `/dev/sdb`: `e2label: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb. Couldn't find a valid filesystem superblock.`

Answer (score 1):

It's the volume label. That's the `-L` flag in `mkfs.ext4` or, I think, the `-n` in mkfs.vfat, and so on.

You can change it by passing a new label to it with `e2label`, or by killing it entirely with `dd`.

Comment: Actually, that's not it. There must be another label. I'm sure "dd" will scratch everything. But why does the stick behave like a weird superposition of disk (it has a partition with a label) and CD-ROM (the whole disk has a label)? I think one will have to go and "use the source, Luke"

Comment: Ah I see you have updated your question a lot. Very interesting investigation! I think looking at dolphin's source would indeed be enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the answer seems to be the following:

1. The name comes from the remainder of the CD-ROM data (which in retrospect is embarrassingly obvious)
2. You can't change it because it's not even meant to be used or even to be there - after all, you want to use the USB flash drive as a disk, not a CD-ROM. These two have different formats. Generally there is no usable string at 0x8000 or 0x9000.
3. Why the name is used when the stick is inserted is unclear. One would have to take a look at the source of whatever part of Linux is responsible for recognizing the format of a block device.

The lesson:

*Reset the USB flash drive by zeroing it before you set up a hard disk partition scheme on it. Otherwise, results will be "undefined" and depend on the heuristics used by the system that reads the flash drive. As seen for `parted`, which detects a mac filesystem.*

P.S.

How to "zero the USB flash drive" in 128K increments (128K should be a 1 or more flash memory cells in size, so any flash memory cell will only be written once):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdXXX bs=128K
```

"zeroing the USB flash drive" is actually and amazingly fraught with unexpected complications. Maybe one should add `count=1024` to keep written blocks low:

- [Can zero-filling reset wear leveling of USB sticks / Flash drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/533474/can-zero-filling-reset-wear-leveling-of-usb-sticks-flash-drives)
- [Do USB flash drives support TRIM? How do they wear-level if they don't?](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2079571)